# CMake: no CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found with Ninja generator in Windows 10

Tags: cmake, windows-10, paraview

I am trying to build the ParaView superbuild (https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview-superbuild) using CMake on Windows 10. They recommend using the Ninja generator.

I downloaded Ninja and put it in `C:/Ninja/ninja.exe`

But I receive this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

Where can I find this compiler?

I installed Visual Studio 13 and 15 and tried to open cmake-gui from the developer's command prompt, but without success.

I have tried other generators. The ParaView superbuild does not work with visual studio. On my Mac I used `Unix MakeFiles` but in Windows 10 it doesn't work, this error appears:

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
```

Comment: The error seems quite clear. Have you installed a compiler? Or what is the issue?

Comment: "I installed Visual Studio 13 and 15 and tried to open cmake-gui from the developer's command prompt, but without success." - Running CMake from the developer's command prompt is a correct way. What error have you got in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt` to run cmake-gui.

Answer (score 0):

Run the editor or command line with "Administrative settings"